# Single Signon between my Azure application and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2010, office365

I am trying to evaluate a strategy where I can integrate our Azure based application to SharePoint Online.
The idea is to provide seamless UI so that they are able to use the best of the features from both these applications without having to navigate away from our application.

We would like to bundle the application with Sharepoint online so that if a user comes to our application they will see another tab for collaboration which will open SharePoint online in a seperate iFrame or something like that.

However the issue here is that we do not want the user to keep another set of user credentials for SharePoint online. Is there a way where we can provide some kind of single sign on here.

Our application uses forms based authentication.

Comment: How you would want to do it, do you have any plan? Using OPENID or ADFS? You sure can use ClaimBased SSO with Azure and SPOnline. Look for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I could verify that you sure can use ClaimBased SSO with Azure and SPOnline. Look for the following:

[Claims-Based Single Sign-On for the Web and Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102.aspx)
[Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx)

So using Claim Based Authentication (Use Windows Azure [ACS](http://acs.codeplex.com/documentation)) you can merge SP online and Azure Web Role together.